# How do I synchronize the scroll position of two divs which contains two trees?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to synchronize two trees in two divs. The trees are two directories with files and I want to show the differences between before and after.

Below the file of the right tree it appears the changes, and I want that the left tree don't scroll down until in the right tree the next file appears.

Comment: Please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please show us what you have tried